# Alternative for correlated update of Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How can I re-write this query to sample update. Can someone decode me for this step by step. Is the whole table1 getting updated here/

```
 UPDATE
    (SELECT 
    A.COLUMN1 A_COLUMN1,
    B.COLUMN2 B_COLUMN2
    FROM TABLE1 A,TABLE2 B
    WHERE A.COLUMN3=B.COLUMN3 AND A.COLUMN4=B.COLUMN4)
    SET A_COLUMN1=B_COLUMN2;
```

Comment: The whole table is not being updated.  Only the matching rows are.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : Thanks, if I write something like this. Update TABLE1 set COLUMN1 = (SELECT 
       B.COLUMN2     FROM TABLE1 A,TABLE2 B
    WHERE A.COLUMN3=B.COLUMN3 AND A.COLUMN4=B.COLUMN4) . Is it correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer the question.

The subquery is using an inner join.  Hence, the subquery will filter out rows that don't match the join conditions in the two tables.  This happens before the update.

Hence, not all the rows get updated.  If you want to update all rows, use a `left join` or:

```
UPDATE TABLE1
    SET A_COLUMN1 = (SELECT B.B_COLUMN2
                     FROM TABLE2 B
                     WHERE A.COLUMN3 = B.COLUMN3 AND A.COLUMN4 = B.COLUMN4
                    );
```

Comment: can you re-write the query for me in simple update and set, please?

Comment: Hi Gordon, Sorry for asking this again. As it's a correlated sub query, all the TABLE2 rows are being searched in TABLE1. It's picking more than necessary. If there are any NULLs in the TABLE1, it is returning as an error in the query. I'm trying to convert the first piece of code into PostgreSQL. So Is there any alternative way of achieving this. SOrry to bother you again.

Answer (score 0):

This way it touches only the common elements

```
UPDATE TABLE1
    SET A_COLUMN1 = (SELECT B.B_COLUMN2
                     FROM TABLE2 B
                     WHERE A.COLUMN3 = B.COLUMN3 AND A.COLUMN4 = B.COLUMN4
                    )
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT B.B_COLUMN2
                     FROM TABLE2 B
                     WHERE A.COLUMN3 = B.COLUMN3 AND A.COLUMN4 = B.COLUMN4);
```